# How do i >install< a platform toolset for a visual studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, solution

i'm trying to open up a C# project on my computer, but visual studio complained that the platform toolset was wrong, it wanted the v141 toolset (from VS2017, im using 2019).

I found many posts on here that asked the same question. But all the answear just talked about how you choose which toolset your project targets, NOT how to actually install it for your computer/project. My dropdown menu for toolsets is completely empty, how do i actually add v141 into the dropdown menu so that i can choose it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open "Visual Studio Installer" (via the start menu). Then click on "change" and choose the "Individual components" tab. There you can select the different runtime toolsets.

[image: I think you need this component]

Comment: Does anyone know how to install a toolset that isn't listed in the individual components tab? I'm trying to install v120_xp from 2013 but cannot find it in the list.

Comment: @Hoppo I don't think these old ones are still supported. So you need to install the visual studio version this version came with.

Comment: Thanks, I just installed VS2013 and that worked.

Comment: This didn’t work for me. I added v141 but the configuration dialog still wouldn’t let me pick it.

Comment: @DavidDunham But it does show other versions? Then check you selected the right item in the installer. There are several entries with "MSVC v141", but they are all very different (e.g. the ARM libraries are of no use when building for windows)